# can produce a very bloody foot -- what does that really mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Source: [Beginning C for Arduino, Second Edition—Learn C Programming for the Arduino by Jack Purdum (2015)](http://www.apress.com/9781484209417)

Example:

> The term void * is a common C idiom used to denote a “typeless” data type pointer in a function declaration. In other words, memcpy() does no type checking during the copy process... it assumes that you know what you are doing and that the pointers all point to valid data! Not paying attention to such details **can produce a very bloody foot**.

Ran a whole bunch of Google searches online, couldn't find anything. Obviously, this is supposed to be some kind of metaphor or an allusion to something. What do you think the author is really trying to say?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose it is a reference to this idiom:

> [shoot yourself in the foot](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shoot+in+the+foot)
>   to do or say something that causes problems for you

So you're going to shoot yourself in the foot if you do not pay "attention to such details". You'll end up with a bloody foot—figuratively.

Comment: I think you really nailed it. That's what he's probably talking about--shooting yourself in the foot. I've actually heard another play on this idiom once in the context of programming. One guy came up with the expression `foot gun` to describe how easy it is that you can get yourself in real trouble with seemingly innocent operators you don't understand the internal workings of well enough.

Comment: Thanks. It's a guess anyway. I think the author was trying to be humorous, but I'm not sure it worked. "Foot gun" haha! That makes sense. Those would be "foot guns".

Comment: That's a good guess though because he did use `shoot yourself in the foot` a couple of times in the text before that.

Comment: I could also see it as a reference to something that "trips you up", but shooting yourself in the foot seems much more likely to result in a bloody foot. Tripping, the worst you'll have is a broken toe.

Comment: Related: the "shoot yourself in the foot in various programming languages" jokes (http://www.toodarkpark.org/computers/humor/shoot-self-in-foot.html, among others).

Comment: Related question on EL&U: [What does it mean 'to shoot oneself in the foot'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/137187/70625)